# Word or phrase for hogging the left lane

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

Frequently on two-lane freeways, at least in the US, people drive in the left lane at exactly the same speed next to a car in the right lane, thus blocking the road.

Cars tend to back up behind these oblivious people. Is there a word or phrase for hogging the left lane?

Comment: I usually call these people "assholes"... but I'm sure there's a better word for it :)

Comment: @Ryan Bigg - No, that word seems perfect.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg - Actually, there are two types of drivers who do this: Assholes and Idiots. It is important to know which is which because an idiot can sometimes be clued in (eg: with your horn), whereas an asshole will just be happier when you honk because they now know they've ticked you off.

Comment: Should we call them "law-abiding"?  At least if they are going *at the speed limit*?

Comment: @GEdgar - As I mentioned in the comments below, in many areas driving for extended periods of time in a "passing lane" is actually against the law.

Comment: I have to mention my favorite phrase for when people don't stay on their side of a driveway or other space that is supposed to be wide enough to allow two-way traffic but because of their position is not: "taking their half out of the middle".

Answer (score 5):

The term I heard most as a kid was [Sunday drivers](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sunday+driver).

> **Sunday driver:**
>   A slow and leisurely driver who appears to be sightseeing and enjoying the view, holding up traffic in the process.

While it's not explicitly about hogging the "fast" lane, I think it gets the point across as far as blocking traffic.

Comment: +1 for Sunday driver. I think it sums it up perfectly.

Comment: Disagree. A `Sunday Driver` will typically be found in the slow lane, but going egregiously slow. It has no implication whatsoever of specifically being in the passing lane.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the simplest (and most polite) phrase is that the person is a [*road hog*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hog):

> Fig. someone who drives carelessly and selfishly.
>
> *Look at that road hog driving in the middle of the road and stopping other drivers from passing him. That road hog nearly knocked the children over. He was driving too fast.*

To capture that the driver is oblivious, another option is [absent-minded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absent-minded):

> so lost in thought that one does not realize what one is doing, what is happening, etc.; preoccupied to the extent of being unaware of one's immediate surroundings.

So you could say,

> That driver in the left lane is so absent-minded! He doesn't realize that there are 5 cars behind him trying to get past.

Comment: That works, but to me connotes a Mr Toad sort of aggressive driving. Forcing people off the road sort of thing... A perfect phrase would hit on- slow; oblivious; clueless.

Comment: A road hog to me seems like someone who is driving on the violeng side e.g. fast and furious. It doesn't give me a picture of leisure and slowness

Comment: How about *lane hog*?

Comment: A "road hog" is generally not driving very slowly at all. This is more a term for the person who cuts off other people when they zip around cars in traffic. Kinda the opposite type of jerk, really.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I think you might be looking for:

> [Left-Lane Camper:](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Left-Lane-Camper-%28slow-driver-in-passing-lane%29-%28LLC%29.html) slow driver in passing lane

Comment: I asked Dr Google and indeed that is in widespread use.

Comment: -1 for leaving out the Brits! :)

Comment: How so? Oh, is it cause Camper is American?

Comment: @Thursagen It's right-lane campers that are more likely to be annoying in the UK and Australia.

Comment: I thought that as the question was american, I might as well keep it american. I'll try looking for a right lane obstacle:)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You should be -1'ing the question then, not this answer. He was just answering the (non-Brit) question as asked.

Comment: +1 anyway, as this is the best answer to the question posed (mine included). It doesn't imply that they are next to someone (and thus blocking traffic), but that's all it is missing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, this is an answer for the question. Your complaint is about the question. If you must, add the AmE tag to the question. Also, any idea if 'right-lane camper' is used or acceptable?

Comment: @Mitch, all: True, I should have downvoted the question, not the answer. But I knew Thursagen would accept the (feeble) joke, and he can afford to lose the rep more than OP. Anyway, so far as I know there is no "right-hand lane" version in the UK. I think mostly we call these people **Sunday drivers**. Or "righteous citizens", since they want everyone to travel at the legal limit of 70mph. The rest of us want to travel at 80-90mph in the outside lane on free-flowing motorways.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No sweat. As for your "righteous citizens"... if you are referring to folk doing this intentionally in order to force a whole highway full of people to stay under their personal favorite speed limit (no matter the other drivers' opinion in the matter), then I think Ryan Bigg had the proper word for them. :-)

Comment: Context is all. When they're in *my* way, these "righteous citizens" are indeed a**holes! :)

Answer (score 3):

The group is referred to as a "[rolling roadblock](http://driverthink.com/2008/01/12/the-rolling-roadblock.aspx)".

Of course that implicitly distributes the blame, where some would rather direct their ire to the schmuck in the left lane who isn't bothering to pass.

However, **it should be noted that sometimes this is done on purpose**. For instance, trucks (who are often in communications with each other via citizen band radios) will occasionally do this when approaching a speed trap, so that no poor unsuspecting soul will get caught.

Also note that in some states (I know Kansas used to be this way) you can get a ticket for doing this. "Traveling in the passing lane" or somesuch. A cynic might postulate this is more so that they have a reason to ticket folks who are preventing their speed traps from working than it is for public safety. But where would we find a cynic on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

*Road Boulder* is a term I've read for a car which impedes the traffic flow (although *traffic boulder* might be a bit more accurate).  A couple of road boulders clumped together can pretty much block traffic.